# BASH-compare datetime in variable

Tags: bash

file st.txt:

```
"succeeded" "test" "2018-03-30T13:42:12Z" "2018-03-30T13:42:21Z"
```

i have a script which returns latest Rundeckjob status

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:4440/api/20/project/Windows-AD/executions?authtoken=r50onM4kXzZ7DhhAN6Fe2rwwxuAhF0IG"  | python -m json.tool > 1.json

jq -r '.|[.executions[] | select(.job.name != null)]  | sort_by(.id)  | reverse  | .[0]  | [.status, .job.name, ."date-started".date, ."date-ended".date] | @csv' 1.json > 1.csv

sed 's/,/ /g' 1.csv>st.txt
while read status name startdate enddate; do
case "$status" in
"\"aborted\"")
echo -1
;;
 "\"failed\"")
echo -1 +  $name
;;
 "\"succeeded\"")
echo 0
;;
*) echo 0 + $name
esac
exit 0
done<st.txt
```

How to compare $start and $enddate ("`2018-03-30T13:42:12Z" "2018-03-30T13:42:21Z"`) and if difference is larger than 5 minutes add another exit "taking too long"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert and compare start/end dates like this:

```
startdate=${startdate//\"/}
stime=$(date -d "${startdate/T/ }" +%s)
enddate=${enddate//\"/}
etime=$(date -d "${enddate/T/ }" +%s)
let elapsed=etime-stime
[ $elapsed -gt 300 ] && echo "taking too long"
```

Comment: There is no need to remove the `T` for GNU date.

Comment: @isaac, not with ast-open `date` either. With busybox `date`, one would need to remove both the `T` and `Z` and add the `-u` option. I don't know of any other `date` implementation that supports that GNU-style `-d` option.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas With busybox date, try this: `busybox date -d '2018-03-30T13:42:12Z' -D '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`..... It raises no error. ...  I shall concede that it does not understand that Z means [Zulu time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) and that it also means UTC, i.e. the `-u` flag is useful in this case to have the resulting time zone as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

GNU date could do the math directly (in seconds).
POSIX script.

```
#!/bin/sh

sd='"2018-03-30T13:42:12Z"'
ed='"2018-03-30T13:42:21Z"' 

sd=${sd#\"}; sd=${sd%\"}    # Remove double quotes.
ed=${ed#\"}; ed=${ed%\"}

ep=$(date -d @0)              # Epoch date (anchor).
ss=$(date -d "$sd" +%s)       # Start time.
es=$(date -d "$ed" +%s)       # End time.
elapsed=$(date -d "$ep - ${ss}sec + ${es}sec" +%s)

if [ "$elapsed" -gt 300 ]]; then 
    echo "taking too long"
fi
```